# How reset "new version" of app in appstore

Tags: app-store, submitchanges

I wonder if there is any way of "resetting" the "new version" of my app in the appStore. NO,
doing a reject of the binary does not seem to be enough.

The problem is the following:
I have this app (found here: www.pekbok.com :) ) that has been poorly localized. so one day, lets call it "Day L", I decided to localize all of its images(iphone and iPad) and upload them into its description on the store. This was a real pain and I sincerely hate these kind of administrative time wasters. Anyways, after "Day L" the app had its images in its correct languages and everything was fine and dandy.

A couple of days Later I decided to upload a new version with lots of fancy-pants stuff in it and went ahead to the itunesconnect. Imagine my surprise when I found that I, some day *before* "Day L" already had added a new version BUT not uploaded any bundle.

It seems to be the case that when one does "add new version" of an existing app, the information about the previous binary is cloned (as a snapshot)and *saved* into new context
of the new version. So, the fact that I have changed the images for my older version does not affect the images of my new version since it was "cloned" before I made these changes("Day L").

I have tried to upload a new binary and rejecting it but the status merely changes to "Rejected by developer" and does not enter its first "add new version"-state :(

please help, I wanna code not spend time on administration :)

Sincerely,
Tommy

Comment: Belongs on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, posted it there. Should I remove my post here or paste answer if given? What do your recommend?

Comment: This kind of question for now has no home at the Stack Exchange network - it is off-topic here for not being about software development. It is also off topic in Ask Different, since it is not about an apple hardware or software. There is a proposal on Area 51 for an [App stores](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) site, but it won't start anytime soon (it is still in the definition phase).

Comment: A related meta question: [where should I ask questions about submitting my app to the app store?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106008/where-should-i-ask-questions-about-submitting-my-app-to-the-app-store)